# How to do a callback on element addEventlister - Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, addeventlistener

I want to do a callback after a eventlistner has completed. My listner looks about this way:

```
  aktivList.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
  $("#printMenu").show();
  $("#imageForm").hide();
  $(".polaroid").hide();
  $("#searchId").hide();
  switch (activeFolderGroupeIs) {
    case "butikkOppgaver":
      firbListnerButikk(firebaseAktivListFolder, ev);
      break;
    case "oppgavelisteAnsatte":
      firbListnerBS(firebaseAktivListFolder, ev);
      break;
    case "varebytteOppgaver":
      firbListnerVarebytte(firebaseAktivListFolder, ev);
      break;
    default:
  };
  if (deleteListMode) {
    deleteMode = true;
    //$("#inputFields").slideUp();
    firebaseRefRemove(currentList, firebasePassivListFolder);
    firebaseRefNumberOfChild();
  };
```

});

When all this code is completed, i want to run another function. (all this functions works as is, but if I add another function at the end, it runs before everything else is finished).

My event listner puts data in textfield. When event lister is completed, i want to run another function. I tried to search for callback and promises, but no one talked about adding it to this code.. any idea?

Regards Jan

Comment: if you just want to call another function, simply call it at the end of your listener "yourFunction();". Unless you give more details about what you're trying to do...

Comment: This eventlistner starts a function who download data from firebase and put it in textfields on web page. When this function is completed, i want to run another function. (I´v tried callbacks, but with no luck..)

Comment: Ok so your problem seems to be related on the asynchronous call to firebase than the event listener. Can you edit your question and put the call to firebase?

Comment: Thanx, I´v edited the question with the event listner code.

Answer (score 1):

You can dispatch a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) to notify when the async operation finished:

**With pure javascript:**

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var txt = document.getElementById('txt');
var myevent = new Event('myEvent');
btn.addEventListener('myEvent', function (e) {console.log('finished the job!')});


btn.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    // async operation here...
    txt.value = 'hi there';
    btn.dispatchEvent(myevent);
  },1000);  
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<input id="txt" type="text" />
```

**With jQuery:**

```js
var btn = $('#btn');
var txtEl = $('#txt');

btn.on("click", function(ev) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // async operation here...
    txtEl.val('hi there');
    btn.trigger('myEvent');
  }, 1000);
});

btn.on('myEvent', function(e) {
  console.log('finished the job!')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<input id="txt" type="text" />
```

Comment: Ok, thanx! I will trie to update my code with this! :)

Comment: if you are already using `jQuery` then [it is easier](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events)

Comment: I´m a newbi so i need to read som more about this, i will trie the different methode. Thanx! :)